# Araxis merge doesn't show file names when merging

Tags: svn, merge, svn-merge, araxis, diff3

I have svn command-line client integrated with Araxis merge and I want to manually merge even when no conflicts discovered. When I run for example:
so in my ~/.subversion/config file I set diff3 external editor:

```
diff3-cmd = /usr/local/bin/araxissvndiff3
```

But when I run

```
svn merge ^/trunk
```

Araxis merge doesn't show actual file name in panel titles, so I don't know the file I am actually merging.

Does anyone know how to make araxis merge show a full file name?

Answer (score 1):

I created this script to solve a similar problem (on Mac OS X):

```
#!/bin/sh

fname="$3"
fname="$(echo ${fname} |sed 's,/[^/]*/,,')"

araxissvndiff3 -L "Merge-From: ${fname}" -L "Result: ${fname}" -L "Merge-To: ${fname}" $2 $1 $3 > $4
exit $?
```

I put it in **/usr/local/bin/araxissvnhelper.sh**, and replaced my references to **araxissvndiff3** with the script in **~/.subversion/config**, like this:

```
merge-tool-cmd=/usr/local/bin/araxissvnhelper.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about additional command-line parameters, see at Windows-centric examples and adopt to your needs

**Differ**

`"C:\Program Files\Araxis\Araxis Merge\compare.exe" /max /wait /title1:%bname /title2:%yname %base %mine`

**Merger**

`"C:\Program Files\Araxis\Araxis Merge\compare.exe" /a2 /max /wait /3 /title1:%tname /title2:%bname /title3:%yname %theirs %base %mine %merged`

Comment: Thank for the advice! But I tried this on Mac and it didn't work.
I use Araxis Merge 2011, Version 2011.4126

Comment: @schatten - at least [here](http://gorn.ch/archive/2008/07/28/resolve-subversion-conflicts-with-araxis-merge.html) I see hint **don't use araxissvndiff3**, but pure compare, maybe araxissvndiff3's parameters doesn't play with window titles

Comment: @schatten - I tried with previous build, on Windows for getting strings from my answer